# Why is std::is_integral<__uint128_t> false with C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to upgrade a legacy application to C++20 and ran into an error that doesn't fail without --std=c++20 on GCC 11.1.0:

```
static_assert(std::is_integral_v<__uint128_t>, "Error: non-integral type");
```

Why is it failing only with C++20 and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: -std=gnu++20 could help?

Comment: Any type that begins with 2 underscores is reserved for the compiler or standard library implementation. There is no *native* `uint128_t` in standard C++ (yet). In this case, either `__uint128_t` is really not implemented as an integral type (maybe it is a struct/class type instead?), or else it is an integral but the compiler vendor probably just forgot to specialize `is_integral` for it.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50441

Answer (score 0):

`std::integral_v` asks whether the type is one of the built-in or implementation-defined "extended integer types". GCC supports no extended integer types.

Thus, according to the rules, it should be false for standard C++.

The `static_assert` will compile with `-std=gnu++20` which enables a number of non-standard behaviors.